# Replacing empty rows with previous non null values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table(**header table**) in SQL server with following columns:

```
name  Eng1 Eng2 Eng3 updateby updateddate
adobe ,  ,Alex,Bob ,John, 2020-09-29 13:10:00
adobe ,Clint, , ,John,    2020-09-29 13:12:00
adobe , ,Mary,  ,John,    2020-09-29 13:14:00
adobe ,Sheila ,,  ,John,  2020-09-29 14:10:00
```

I want to ***fill empty rows with previous non null data,if any***. So, the resultant table/view should become:

```
     name  Eng1 Eng2 Eng3 updateby updateddate
    adobe ,     ,Alex,Bob,John, 2020-09-29 13:10:00
    adobe ,Clint,Alex,Bob,John,    2020-09-29 13:12:00
    adobe ,Clint,Mary,Bob,John,    2020-09-29 13:14:00
    adobe ,Sheila,Mary,Bob,John,  2020-09-29 14:10:00
```

I am using below view but it fails to provide the solution:

```
WITH RANKTABLE AS
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name,updateddate) rnk 
    FROM Header
)

SELECT name,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Eng1 FROM RANKTABLE a WHERE a.rnk = 
    (SELECT MAX(b.rnk) FROM RANKTABLE b WHERE b.rnk <= c.rnk AND b.Eng1 IS NOT NULL)) as Eng1_Updated,

    (SELECT TOP 1 Eng2 FROM RANKTABLE a WHERE a.rnk = 
    (SELECT MAX(b.rnk) FROM RANKTABLE b WHERE b.rnk <= c.rnk AND b.Eng2 IS NOT NULL)) as Eng2_Updated,

    (SELECT TOP 1 Eng3FROM RANKTABLE a WHERE a.rnk = 
    (SELECT MAX(b.rnk) FROM RANKTABLE b WHERE b.rnk <= c.rnk AND b.Eng3  IS NOT NULL)) as Eng3_Updated
From RANKTABLE c
```

Comment: Presumably, you want a separate computation for each name, although that is not clear from the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full edit using new test data and solution code...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RankTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN DROP TABLE #RankTable; END;

CREATE TABLE #RankTable (
    name varchar(10),
    Eng1 varchar(10),
    Eng2 varchar(10),
    Eng3 varchar(10),
    updateby varchar(10),
    updateddate datetime
    );
INSERT #RankTable (name, Eng1, Eng2, Eng3, updateby, updateddate) VALUES
    ('adobe', NULL, 'Mary', 'Bob', 'John', '2020-09-29 13:10:00'),
    ('adobe', 'Walter', NULL, NULL, 'John', '2020-09-29 13:12:00'),
    ('adobe', NULL, 'Alex', NULL, 'John', '2020-09-29 13:14:00'),
    ('adobe', 'Sheila', NULL, NULL, 'John', '2020-09-29 14:10:00');


--SELECT * FROM #RankTable rt;

SELECT 
    rt.name,
    Eng1 = CONVERT(varchar(10), SUBSTRING(MAX(bv.binval_1) OVER (PARTITION BY rt.[name] ORDER BY rt.updateddate), 9, 10)),
    Eng2 = CONVERT(varchar(10), SUBSTRING(MAX(bv.binval_2) OVER (PARTITION BY rt.[name] ORDER BY rt.updateddate), 9, 10)),
    Eng3 = CONVERT(varchar(10), SUBSTRING(MAX(bv.binval_3) OVER (PARTITION BY rt.[name] ORDER BY rt.updateddate), 9, 10)),
    rt.updateby,
    rt.updateddate
FROM
    #RankTable rt
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
            CONVERT(binary(8), rt.updateddate) + CONVERT(varbinary(10), rt.Eng1),
            CONVERT(binary(8), rt.updateddate) + CONVERT(varbinary(10), rt.Eng2),
            CONVERT(binary(8), rt.updateddate) + CONVERT(varbinary(10), rt.Eng3)
            ) ) bv (binval_1, binval_2, binval_3);
```

Results...

```
name       Eng1       Eng2       Eng3       updateby   updateddate
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------------------
adobe      NULL       Mary       Bob        John       2020-09-29 13:10:00.000
adobe      Walter     Mary       Bob        John       2020-09-29 13:12:00.000
adobe      Walter     Alex       Bob        John       2020-09-29 13:14:00.000
adobe      Sheila     Alex       Bob        John       2020-09-29 14:10:00.000
```

Comment: This is not working as intended, Jason. It does not carry forward names. For example, I have three rows of data. Eng1 = Clint on date 1/1/2020 , Eng1 = Jacob on date 1/2/2020, the third entry is Eng1 = null value on date 1/3/2020. I expect that the third value becomes 'Jacob'.. but it is not happening

Comment: @CodeMaster... Yes it does. I'll update the answer to include the output result set.

Comment: hmm.. so strange it is not working on my end. What is the "ranktable" definition you are using? This is my code right now:

Comment: With RANKTABLE AS
(
SELECT  NAME,ENG1,ENG2,UPDATED_DATE,UPDATED_BY,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY API_NO14, UPDATED_DATE) rnk
FROM  MainTable
)
SELECT 
    rt.API_NO14,
    ENG1 = MAX(rt.ENG1) OVER (PARTITION BY rt.NAME ORDER BY rt.UPDATED_DATE),
    ENG2 = MAX(rt.ENG2) OVER (PARTITION BY rt.NAME ORDER BY rt.UPDATED_DATE),
  rt.UPDATED_BY,
  rt.UPDATED_DATE
FROM
    RANKTABLE rt

Comment: Thanks... so, it fails at one step: If the Eng1 entries are : Null, Clint, Steve, Shiela. I noticed that Shiela gets replaced with Steve. That should not happen....

Comment: @CodeMaster... No, Shella does not get replaced with Steve. There is no Steve is your example data. I updated my answer with both the CREATE TABLE and the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222673/discussion-between-codemaster-and-jason-a-long).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a pain, but you can use window functions.  You can define the groups by counting the number of non-null values up to each row.  Then spread the value around:

```
select h.*,
       max(eng1) over (partition by name, grp1) as imputed_eng1,
       max(eng2) over (partition by name, grp2) as imputed_eng2,
       max(eng3) over (partition by name, grp3) as imputed_eng3
from (select h.*,
             count(eng1) over (partition by name order by updateddate) as grp1,
             count(eng2) over (partition by name order by updateddate) as grp2,
             count(eng3) over (partition by name order by updateddate) as grp3
      from header h
     ) h;
```

The above has separate processing for each `name`.  I am guessing that is the intention of the question.  If not, just remove `name` from the `partition by`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a7cacbef6fd9b77cd062fd6e35b42f60) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: this solution has a flaw but probably works for his scenario ,ex, If there is a bunch of null eng1's and then one with another value , and then null, after the second value, the  second null values should get the second updated value, which the query above doesn't provide a solution for that.

Comment: @Ehsan . . . Would you care to explain what you think the flaw is?  A comment such as yours is eminently unhelpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you have "grp1" & "grp_1"... throwing an error...

Comment: @GordonLinoff this does not work. Basically the imputed group values are displayed as in the database. no carry forward happened.

Comment: @CodeMaster . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  This does impute the values exactly as your question describes.